# SSL connection handshake failed on Android

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, tls1.2

I my application, I try to download from SSL connection on android, below is my code

```
 String url = "https://mysslconnection/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx";

        try{
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            while(null != (strStoreList = reader.readLine())){
                System.out.println(strStoreList);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String exception = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(exception);

        }
```

I encounter exception - handshake failed. I do not know how to fix it so I searched from internet and I can see a lot of topics on that. But I would like to study from begin on how to setup ssl connection, use keystore, create SSLSocketFactory ... Could any one recommend document or link on that? I have read one from android develop https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html
but it's not enough.

Comment: I would recommend using retrofit,in case you want to workaround your exception and use retrofit https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client , if you want to use selfsigned certificate with retrofit http://xperience57.blogspot.com.eg/2016/05/using-self-signed-certificate-with.html

Comment: @john-aziz57 Thanks, let me read it

Comment: You can also test your https server with ssllabs.com , to be sure it's working properly.

Comment: I was getting "Handshake failed" as well, but created the URL object using the component constructor (protocol, server, etc). For this you need to set the port to 443 for SSL - and not the usual 80 for http. I don't know if the URL constructor you're using does this automatically?